# AngularJS Convert Object to Array

Tags: angularjs

I have an object coming from database
`tabletName.1.atablet tabletName.2.btablet tabletName.3.ctablet`

where atablet, btablet and ctablet are tablet names.

How can  convert it into an array tabletName:

```
index 0 : atablet
index 1 : btablet
index 2 : ctablet
```

I want to use the array as

```
ngmodel="tabletName[0]"
ngmodel="tabletName[1]"
ngmodel="tabletName[2]"
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your original nor your desired data structure

Comment: Have you listened about javascript? Looks like it could help you

Comment: I have an php array tabletName[0],tabletName[1] coming into angular js Without json_encode, so i get phparray as angularjs object. In the form the ng-model is used as  an array as in the edited question.

Comment: Then use `json_encode`, its bad practise if you parse an php (printed with `print_r`) array with javascript to JSON.

Comment: Nano i cannot change the php code presently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to angularjs and hence unclear question. Please remove the downvote for question.

I solved the issue as : used an array of objects with ng-repeat.

The question is not proper so you can ignore.